# Using the Parse.com Object Column

Tags: swift, parse-platform, subclass

I cannot find documentation on the Parse.com table column `Object` data type. I assume it is an object in the context of software development. However, what is the syntax to use to enter an object into the object column? I would be interested to know both the programmatic steps to take (not too concerned about which language, more concerned about actions to take to save to the object column), but I would be even more interested to know how to enter an object into the table from the Parse.com website. Can we do this from the Data section of the "Core" tab, in the Parse.com Dev webpage for the app?

I did this little test in Swift to try and save an object with a property of type object (myCar) to the table from code (I have a Parse.com table with class name Test, which has an object column called myCar). It is causing an error (I'm new to iOS so cannot find out much about the error):

Car class

```
class Car {
    var doors = 4
    func addDoor() {
        doors++
    }
}
```

client code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        var testMan = PFObject(className:"Test")
        var car = Car()
        testMan["myCar"] = car //////////////// error here
        testMan.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                // The object has been saved.

                println("Success")
            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
                println("Failure")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't set a variable to be _an entire class_ thats your first and most important issue. Additionally, here is a Parse.com documentation you can't seem to find : [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects)

Comment: @soulshined I am talking about when you add a class from the data section of the core tab in Parse.com. This is otherwise known as a table. And you give it a column. And you set that column type to be object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, u're mixing swift objects with parse objects .. if you want a Car object linked to your Test class you must create it in parse database (+ add class -> car -> and then create properties in it). When you have created parse class Car u can use it in swift code as `let car = PFObjecT(className: "Car")` and later on assign that class to test object with `testMan["myCar"] = car`

Comment: Thanks. Can I add a Car() to my test object from the Parse website or only in code?

Comment: u must create car class on parse website and after doing that u can later put it in code